# Ubuntu 11.10 and DMD?

Tags: ubuntu, d

I just install DMD compiler from http://www.digitalmars.com/d/download.html for Ubuntu 64 bits (dmd_2.055-0_amd64.deb). But when I try tu run a simple hello.d

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    writeln("hello");
}
```

with the command on a terminal :$dmd hello.d

displays the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a(datetime_48b_1ec.o): In function `_D3std8datetime5Clock11currStdTimeFNdNeZl':
std/datetime.d:(.text._D3std8datetime5Clock11currStdTimeFNdNeZl+0x1d): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a(time_c0_4d1.o): In function `_D4core4time12TickDuration12_staticCtor7OFNeZv':
src/core/time.d:(.text._D4core4time12TickDuration12_staticCtor7OFNeZv+0x1f): undefined reference to `clock_getres'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a(time_c0_4d1.o): In function `_D4core4time12TickDuration14currSystemTickFNdNeZS4core4time12TickDuration':
src/core/time.d:(.text._D4core4time12TickDuration14currSystemTickFNdNeZS4core4time12TickDuration+0x1f): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
--- errorlevel 1
```

I don't know what's the problem and I can't find the solution on the web.

Answer (score 6):

This was discussed here: http://www.digitalmars.com/webnews/newsgroups.php?art_group=digitalmars.D&article_id=146675

Try editing `/etc/dmd.conf` and moving `-L-lphobos2` before `-L-lrt` on the `DFLAGS` line.

Comment: It's been fixed for the next release (2.056): http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=6822